# Replacing colon with comma

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have time entries of the form:

```
12:45:55:346 (hh:mm:ss:mss)
```

And I want to convert it to the form:

```
12:45:55,346 (hh:mm:ss,mss)
```

How shall I proceed, please?

Comment: have you tried defining your own format?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [SUBSTITUTE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/substitute-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332) and specify the 4th parameter:

With input in A1:
    =SUBSTITUTE(A1,":",",",3)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-4) & "," & RIGHT(A1,3)
```

[image]

Comment: Or better use `=VALUE(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-4) & "," & RIGHT(A1,3))` to get it as a date/time value and format it as `hh:mm:ss,000` if you want to calculate with it.

Answer (score 0):

This formula will do the trick:

```
=REPLACE(A1, 9, 1, ",")
```

[image]

> Although this is not something I'd exactly recommend and is likely to
>   mess up your formatting.
>
> If you truly insist on using this formatting, then keep the original data in a hidden column and do all the calculations with it. The data in this format should just be used to display the current / final result(s).